# SQL 2014 Maintenance Plan logging errors

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have a maintenance plan running on SQL 2016. The maintenance plan executes correctly; however, every time it runs it logs 40 - 50 errors:

"Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. ERROR: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 8"

'sa' is the Database owner on all databases. The 'sa" password is correct because it is used to log into the Server Management Studio.

I have run "select suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases" and the owner is 'sa' on all databases.

It looks like a credentials problem but I have created Backup credentials with this username and password.

I am using "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"

Is anyone else experiencing anything similar?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The password provided is not correct for sa. On another topic, why are you using sa for anything? You should be using a proper user.

Comment: I have run into this problem.  I turned on login audit: failed and successful logins.  When I run the maintenance plan the user will work for everything except six failures all in the same maintenance plan.  I trimmed down my plan to be just be maintenance clean up and check DB integrity.  It fails on DB integrity even when I trim it down to a single DB.  If I copy the generated script and run it under the same account it works. Any ideas for an answer to this problem?